# Change AppPool of Application programmatically

Tags: c#, iis-7

I need to change the app pool of all/selected applications under a certain website.
I got all websites and App Pools on my IIS, but I can't change them.
Any ideas?

Here's what I've done so far...
It looks strange to me, because there's only string changing, not object.

```
private void ChangeAppPool()
{
    Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site site = (Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site)this.websiteList.SelectedItem;
    Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool appPool = (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool)this.appPoolCombo.SelectedItem;

    site.Stop();
    site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = appPool.Name;

    foreach (var item in site.Applications)
    {
        item.ApplicationPoolName = appPool.Name;
    }

    site.Start();
    appPool.Recycle();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I modified your given code to **use [ServerManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class** as your code did not work for me. (what is `this.websiteList.SelectedItem`? cast string to Site?)

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
Site site = serverManager.Sites[0]; // get site by Index or by siteName
ApplicationPool appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[1]; // get appPool by Index or by appPoolName

site.Stop();
site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = appPool.Name;

foreach (var item in site.Applications)
{
    item.ApplicationPoolName = appPool.Name;
}

serverManager.CommitChanges();  // this one is crucial!!! see MSDN: 
// Updates made to configuration objects must be explicitly written to the configuration 
// system by using the CommitChanges method!!
site.Start();
appPool.Recycle();
```

Comment: selectedItem was the object. Selected through the combobox. Thanks for your answer!