# Application pool Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an asp.net app and I want when this app is running on IIS,to run under an application pool with classic pipeline mode.

I know how to fix it through the IIS manager but I am wondering if it is possible to fix it from my app. I want either to change the pool or change the managed pipeline mode of the defaultAppPool.

Thank you

Comment: I could imagine running my application on shared host and changing application pool settings from my application. Sounds terrible

Comment: is it possible to change the application pool?there are other pools with classic mode

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12147721/492258)

Comment: Impossible in such case. A web application should not attempt to control IIS settings as that's a security design.

Comment: If I want to change the application pool that the app is running? I believe that this not affects other apps.

Answer (score 0):

If your application have the right permission you may run this command line:

```
appcmd set app /app.name:string /applicationPool:string
```

The variable app.namestring is the name of the application that you want to change, and the variable applicationPoolstring is the name of the application pool to which you want to add the application

reference: [Change an Application Pool for an Application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731755(v=ws.10).aspx)

You can run a command line from your application using the [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx) function, and a simple example : [How to redirect command line output to a ASPX page using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807856/how-to-redirect-command-line-output-to-a-aspx-page-using-c/25808075#25808075)